# Is it possible to make a formula for median that works with both even or odd amounts of values?

Tags: statistics, median

Everyone here probably knows the median formula. It's the middle number of the set if the number of values in the set is odd, or the average of the two middle numbers in the set if the number of values in the set is even. But, I've always been left wondering, Is it possible to make a formula for median that works with both even or odd amounts of values?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give a formula just restricted to even (or odd)?

Comment: For an ordered sequence $a_i,0\geq i\geq n$, it should be $\bar a=(a_{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}+a_{\lceil n/2\rceil})/2$ I think.

Comment: ^ yes, this is the "combined formula" using floor and ceiling functions on the indices (typo $0\le i\le n$)

Comment: @Angelica oh thanks! Can you write this in an answer?

Comment: @PrasunBiswas also thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an ordered sequence $a_i$ defined for $0\leq i\leq n$, the median $\bar a$ of the sequence is given by:

$$\bar a=\frac{a_{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}
+a_{\left\lceil\frac{n}{2}\right\rceil}}{2}$$

Comment: Though note that involves a sequence of $n+1$ terms